# Calculate age in months given date of birth - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Could someone give me an example of a function that would return an integer (how many months old) based on a persons age when given the date of birth?

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “an integer based on a persons age”?

Comment: How old the person is in months. Sorry didn't specify that in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Function AgeInMonths(ByVal birthDate As Date) As Long
    Return Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateDiff(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Month, birthDate, Date.Today)
End Function
```

Comment: `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` arithmetic operators are inadequate for calendar operations, you have to use `Calendar` methods to do what the questioner asks. Normally I try to avoid the VB6 compatibility stuff, but `DateDiff` is such a time-saver compared to the official methods that I am happy to use it to improve code readability.

Comment: You are completely right. Which is why I have removed my unqualified comment and gave you a +1 after reading up in the documentation.